# Collect unique active record objects from array in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a result of query that returns more than 50k records. I do :

```
@array.collect {|x| x.field_name1}.uniq, @array.collect {|x| x.field_name2}.uniq
```

..to create a filter for several selects in the view.
It takes quite a while. Is there any way I can collect all unique elements in one loop in order to improve the performance?
Thanks

Comment: It's a good question though..

Answer (score 11):

Pure Ruby/Rails approach (without hardcoded SQL) for selecting unique column values would be:

```
uniq_fields1 = Model.uniq.pluck(:field_1)
# issues: SELECT DISTINCT field_1 FROM "models"
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
unique_field_1_values = Set.new
unique_field_2_values = Set.new
@array.each do |x|
  unique_field_1_values << x
  unique_field_2_values << x
end
```

only iterates through the array once and gives you two sets with the unique values for the field. Don't know for sure whether it's faster though.

Comment: I think it would faster to get unique elements directly in the SQL query, not in Ruby.

Comment: Quite possibly, especially depending on the indexes although I think you'd need one query for each attribute.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I haven't thought about sets at all. That fits my needs. i can't use distinct sql query as i need to use later the results. I thought it's better to query the db only once and then process the results.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @tokland's comment:

```
[:field1, :field2].map { |f| YourTable.select(f).uniq }
```

As @Frederick notes that is indeed two hits to the db, but will (likely) be faster, and will almost definitely be faster if you have indexes on those fields.

Comment: You'll get relations, not values (which is what is needed, judging from the author's code).

Comment: Indeed. Cross-post gets me again. You had me at `pluck`.You had me at `pluck`.

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't misunderstood the question, `uniq` should give you unique objects as well:

```
array_of_objects.uniq
```

[Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)